# Why am I still being served my entire application when I'm using res.send("HELLO WORLD") in ExpressJS

Tags: angularjs, express

We are using the MEAN stack for this project, and we have client side routing via AngularJS as well if that's important. However, I'm wondering why the client receives any files at all since we are only sending "Hello World". Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Realized the problem has to do with 
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
but removing this makes it impossible to serve the CSS/JS/other resources to the user.

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app); // pass our application into our routes

// start app ===============================================
app.listen(port);

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
exports = module.exports = app; 

//File: ./app/routes
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.send("HELLO WORLD");
    });
}
```

Comment: can you explain in details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, this was to do with `express.static` serving your angular app for each request.

You can do two things:

1. Add different static (so express serves static files from multiple directories) paths like so:

   ```
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/img'));
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
   ```
2. Move your routes above your static files / or serve angular app manually like so:

   ```
   // test for the route before serving static content
   app.get('/', function(req, res){
       //Send your app on this req
   })
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
   ```

   This will mean that express will evaluate the request and try to find a matching route before looking for static content.